# How to pass Observable attribute to component in Angular2?

Tags: angular, data-binding, observable

Try to pass attribute of an Observable object to component like this:

```
<bookmark [type]="'store'" [targetId]="(store | async)?.id" [endDate]="99999999999999"></bookmark>
```

But targetId always undefined. What's the correct way do that?

Comment: can you share the component code where this is set? Also, you dont need to use async and ? together.

Comment: try using `[targetId]="store?.id | async"`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are doing it right, but i guess you are facing another problem..

let me demonstrate it here: https://plnkr.co/edit/AE67JyXZ5hg6A1ahrm7E?p=preview

If it's a "normal" observable, the view will only be updated when an event is fired AFTER the view is initiated!

If there were an event BEFORE, it will NOT be shown!

Therefore you should use the `BehaviorSubject`, which will "buffer" the last value.

```js
@Component({
  selector: 'my-app',
  template: `
    <div>
      <h2>Hello {{name}}</h2>

      <br />
      without timeout: {{ (testWoTimeout | async)?.any }} <!-- will not be shown -->

      <br />
      with timeout: {{ (test | async)?.any }} <!-- will be shown cause of that timeout -->

      <br />
      behavior subject: {{ (behaviorTest | async)?.any }} <!-- will be shown cause of that BehaviorSubject -->
    </div>
  `,
})
export class App {
  name:string;

  test = new Subject();
  testWoTimeout = new Subject();
  behaviorTest = new BehaviorSubject({ any: 'default' });

  constructor() {
    this.name = 'Angular2'
  }

  ngOnInit() {

    this.testWoTimeout.next({ any: 'prop' }); // this will not be shown, cause its fired before the view was initiated!

    this.behaviorTest.next({ any: 'prop' });

    setTimeout(() => {
      this.test.next({ any: 'prop' });
    }, 250);
  }
}
```